# group two different names of radio by row in bucle?

Tags: html, forms, radio-button

```
<body>
   <table>
       <tr>
             <td><input type="radio" name="red"></td>
             <td><input type="radio" name="green"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
             <td><input type="radio" name="red"></td>
             <td><input type="radio" name="green"></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
             <td><input type="radio" name="red"></td>
             <td><input type="radio" name="green"></td>
       </tr>
   </table>
</body>
```

I want check only one input by row, without count with the others rows

Comment: Please elaborate more . Also as `name` are same so at a time you can check only one radio .

Comment: Yes I understand, but I want to group them that way, since then I will obtain the same chosen name of each row through a getparameterValues ()

Comment: So for row 1 give same name for both input then for next row give both input same name ..etc .